# CAS: javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException: Unrecognized Callback:

Tags: spring-mvc, authentication, jakarta-ee, weblogic, cas

I am using CAS authentication in my Spring MVC application deployed in a WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.2.0.0.

The CAS server (http://www.jasig.org/cas)

– Serves CAS login web page and authenticates users

– Issues TGT cookie (ticket granting ticket) so user does not have to
login every redirect to CAS server

– Redirects back to application server with ticket=ST-xxx service ticket
in url for CAS client to check

– Validates CAS service tickets for application servers

But everytime I refresh the page I realized that the ticket parameter is different,

```
http://127.0.0.1:7001/devices_admin/welcome/welcome.do?ticket=ST-4857110-xJpv1gJ85niEGKBJHnQ5XZ5Et8pPY2kdXXkRzOlywdipakotoWUodeh4WCcovXPHWWxqbM6M0zNjxDy4uWSuazG-PHslUMVSXYCWTApMlTfLGC-m8dJiJ6e0zsxwwPOhzc5uNsRJh4dpl1mWcPdxaYhj21G    
http://127.0.0.1:7001/devices_admin/welcome/welcome.do?ticket=ST-4860089-wzJ3y2wzsMYHmpl8H7CenIURY68LSu0xzSKNB2o0XZiOrR60FGQHN9wSo83MuUraWFavzn3Qlp6VhtOzSEvdfwY-PHslUMVSXYCWTApMlTfLGC-JJBSzIydnDGzcECwzsiDiYCLUVecvzxZHmjIN2kDTewo
```

so I get a Error 404--Not Found in the browser

```
Error 404--Not Found



From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:

10.4.5 404 Not Found

The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.

If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 403 (Forbidden) can be used instead. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.
```

Here my weblogic.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app   xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" 
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd 
                                        http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app 
                                        http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">


    <!-- Example of a role mapped to a group provided by Ecas -->
    <session-descriptor>     
        <cookie-path>/devices_admin</cookie-path>        
        <cookie-name>DEVICESJSESSIONID</cookie-name>        
        <url-rewriting-enabled>false</url-rewriting-enabled>        
    </session-descriptor>
    <context-root>/devices_admin</context-root>     
    <security-role-assignment>
        <role-name>authenticated</role-name>
        <principal-name>INTERNET</principal-name>       
    </security-role-assignment>         
    <!-- Only needed if you want to allow some resources to be accessed by  authenticated users who do not possess any role -->
    <container-descriptor>
        <allow-all-roles>true</allow-all-roles>
    </container-descriptor>               
    <jsp-descriptor>
        <precompile>true</precompile>
    </jsp-descriptor>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

There is also an exception start the WL

```
javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException: Unrecognized Callback       at weblogic.security.BaseCallbackHandler.handle(BaseCallbackHandler.java:44)
       at weblogic.security.BaseCallbackHandler.handle(BaseCallbackHandler.java:32)
       at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.CallbackHandlerWrapper.handle(CallbackHandlerWrapper.java:76)
       at weblogic.security.service.internal.WLSJAASLoginServiceImpl$CallbackHandlerWrapper.handle(WLSJAASLoginServiceImpl.java:154)
       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$SecureCallbackHandler$1.run(LoginContext.java:947)
       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$SecureCallbackHandler$1.run(LoginContext.java:944)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$SecureCallbackHandler.handle(LoginContext.java:943)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your spring xml file where have configured your service properties. Your callback url is usually configured in "service" property. This URL is usually your client application URL where you want the request to be redirected once the CAS has authenticated.